# Load my question after I submit it in the Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

Given the main site shows the posted question I think the Android app should go to the posted question once it's been submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was implemented a very long time ago, sorry about forgetting to update this request.